# how to show picklist values in different languages dependent on the current user’s country?

Tags: picklist, custom-field, page-layout, language

I want to show picklist values in the language of the logged in user.  (don't want to use VF pages)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Translation Workbench for that.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workbench_overview.htm&type=5